# How to implement spectrogram in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, spectrogram

Here is the image of the spectrogram I am trying to make in flutter. The theme is to record an audio and then play it and the graph will replicate the data according to the audio. Recording audio was the easy stuff but I am unable to create a graph like this one.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEyEO.png)

I haven't found any plugins regarding this. Have anyone tried this yet?